# Zero Factorial Returning 1 Recursively

Tags: java, recursion, factorial

How can I get this recursive method to return `1` on calling `0!` without testing for a base case, that is without doing an `if-else` for 0 and 1.

```
public static long f( number ){
        if ( number <= 1 ){ // test for base case
                return 1; // base cases: 0! = 1 and 1! = 1
            } 
        else{ return number * f( number - 1 ); }
   }
```

I don't want to check for base cases. Is this possible?

Comment: You're always going to need a base-case.  So what's the problem?

Comment: you should avoid the recursive implementation of factorial anyway because the stack overhead is very expensive compared to the loop overhead. if you would be in a pure functional language you'd still be stuck with defining the base case as f(0) = 1.

Comment: If you mean no if-else _statement_ you can use a conditional _expression_: `return number <= 1 ? 1 : number * f*(number - 1)` but you do have to test. :)

Comment: @Alex - the chances are that performance is not relevant to what the OP is doing.

Comment: @StephenC indeed. I wanted to point out that this piece of code might be correct but it is an inferior implementation compared to the loop one, when it comes to performance. Coding is not just about the beauty of the code, one should also consider the impact of the chosen implementation.

Comment: @Alex - and I wanted to point out that a less performant implementation is not necessarily inferior. "Beauty" is beside the point.  The important issues are whether the code is **maintainable** and whether it **works as required**.  Performance should only be a primary focus (e.g. at the cost of readability) if it is a real requirement.  (Granted, we are quibbling - neither performance or readability are real concerns for `factorial(long)`.  But in non-trivial cases it matters.)

Comment: @StephenC indeed you are right. I think going both ways is dangerous: having code that is trimmed for absolute performance is hardly maintainable and having code that is just **correct** but is too slow on a complexity level. If you implement an algorithm that has O(n^2) complexity and O(n log(n)) is possible by just using a map instead of a list you can't say it's less maintainable -- just a more appropriate solution.

Comment: @Alex - I agree that more performant solutions are not *necessarily* less maintainable.  But `O(N^2)` is not *necessarily* too slow either ... even if you have an `O(1)` solution available.  The key question is whether there is a *real need* that the algorithm be fast.  Because if there isn't, striving for speed is pointless as striving for "beauty".  (Besides, `O(N^2)` is only guaranteed to be slower than `O(NlogN)` for large enough `N`.)

Comment: @StephenC An interesting point of view! I usually code in embedded environments. if you use tail-recursions you rely on the fact that the optimizer will remove the function calls. if you debug without optimizations you'll run into stackoverflows for this factorial at n=1000 (4kb memory). In my experience more time is wasted when you try get a working solution first and then try to optimize it until it fits your needs. But this environment has natural code and memory constraints. I am sure this is entirely different in enterprise software.

Comment: @Alex - The Java compilers don't do tail-call optimization.  However, you'll run into `long` overflow before you run into stack overflow - `factorial(21)` is greater than `2^64`!  But you have a point.  When you use a recursive algorithm there is a potential **correctness** issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using an if-else or `? :` is the best solution.  I.e. anything els eis likely to be worse.

```
public static long f(int n){
  try {
    return 0 / n + n * f(n-1);
  } catch(ArithmeticException ae) {
    return 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: It does feel worth noting for the benefit of the OP that this is still doing a base check, its just checking by doing `0/n` and catching the exception when n = 0. I say this mainly because I worry that this got the accepted answer (no offence, Peter).

Comment: @Mob: cool. I assumed the prohibition was on base checks entirely rather than just on using if/else for them.

Comment: This answer is only useful for interviewers who think they are being smart. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Every recursive function needs a termination condition that has to be explicitly checked for. If there was none, it would run forever. So no, it is not possible to omit that base case check

Answer (score 2):

> I don't want to check for base cases. Is this possible?

No, it is not possible.  You have to test for the base case otherwise the algorithm won't terminate.

Answer (score 2):

You only need check the case of `0` (and for integrity, less than 0 as well) although you need ***a*** base case otherwise you'll just run in an infinite loop (or until you hit a stack overflow). You can shorten the code though:

```
public static long f(int n){
    if (n<0) throw new InvalidParameterException();
    return n == 0 ? 1 : n * f(n-1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, the base case as you call it is the condition to stop the recursion... How do you want to stop recursion without test?

On the other hand, iterative version should be faster.

Answer (score 1):

You always need base-case checking for recursion to make it finite. BTW, base-case for 0 is in factorial definition.

Answer (score 0):

As others say, you need a base case, but you don't have to check for it. The following leads to very bad code, so don't try this at home. It's just a proof of concept.

Define an array (index 0 to 21) of functions. Each function takes a parameter `n`. The function at index 0 returns 1 for any `n`, all others return `n` times the return value of the function at index `n-1`. Start with calling the function at index `n`. No if-else, no check for anything.

An array size of 21 is enough, because at `21!` the given return type `long` (64bit) overflows and the result is undefined anyway. If you want to avoid the OutOfBound exception, you can add a wrapper that calls the function with `min (n, 21)`.